# Best way to run a GLMM with max, min, and average of the same variables

Tags: glm, glmm

I have a dataset consisting of "total activity" (a count variable, number of observations per day) and many predictor variables (temperature, humidity, etc.). I have the daily maximum, minimum, and average for each variable. I want to use a GLM or GLMM to model which variables are the most predictive of total activity. What is the best way to handle this in a model since max, min and average of the same variable are highly correlated, and some of the weather variables (temperature and humidity) are also highly correlated? I am relatively new to modeling, so please excuse the ignorance.

I have tried running separate models, but it doesn't seem reasonable to try and run every combination of every model using maximum, minimum, and average.